# What does it mean when someone says they have sparse labels?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm going through the Hands-On Machine Learning book with Scikit-Learn and TF by Aurelion Geron and I've come across the notion of choosing a specific loss function due to the data having sparse labels.

The specific quote is

> This code requires some explanation. First, we use the
>   "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" loss because we have sparse labels
>   (i.e., for each instance, there is just a target class index, from 0
>   to 9 in this case), and the classes are exclusive. If instead we had
>   one target probability per class for each instance (such as one-hot
>   vectors, e.g. [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.] to represent
>   class 3), then we would need to use the "categorical_crossentropy"
>   loss instead.

The thing is this is different than my understanding of a sparse vector where most of the values are 0. So what are sparse labels?

Answer (score 2):

imagen you have a target class with 10 target classes: `class 0, class 2, ...., class 9`

In the first example you will have only one target column called sparse labels, e.g.:

```
columnA columnB target
10      10       0
1       24       2
...
```

in the second exmaple you will have one target column for every class:

```
columnA columnB class 0 class 1 class 2 ....
10      10       1       0       0      ...
1       24       0       0       1      ...
```

Comment: I don't really see why this would be called "sparse" though.

Comment: I think they mean sparse such that if you see the class columns as a matrix then it would be a sparse matrix which means that most of its entries will be zeros (in this case only one entry per rows is not zero). If you had, for example, many classes for each data point then this matrix is not necessarily sparse.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that if you only have one label indicating which class the instance belong to, it is sparse in the sense that is limited to a single class assignment. The matrix version of this is the one-hot vectors representation which only has mostly zeros and only 1 ones on the correpsonding class (which is a sparse matrix). More generally you can use a matrix in which each element indicates the probability for the instance to belong to a specific class (which is not sparse matrix).